# Сжать Flex-контейнер, который находится внутри другого Flex-контейнера

Tags: css, вёрстка, flexbox, адаптивная-верстка

Почему при уменьшении высоты внешнего контейнера не уменьшается высота `top-container` и вложенных в него элементов (`#first`, `#second`, `#third`) ?

При этом если задать высоту непосредственно для элемента `top-container`, то вложенные элементы всё же сжимаются...

Как заставить сжиматься flex-контейнер с его потомками, вложенный в другой flex-контейнер ?:)

```css
.outer-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 450px;
}

.top-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  background: rgba(200,0,0,.5);
}

.top-container div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 0 1 120px;
  min-height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.bottom-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: none;
  
  background: rgba(0,200,0,.5);
}

.bottom-container div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
   <div class="top-container">
    <div id="first">111</div>
    <div id="second">222</div>
    <div id="third">333</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-container">
    <div id="four">4</div>
    <div id="five">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Потому что вы задали этим блокам высоту в `flex: 0 1 120px;`

Comment: Даже если не выставлять flex-basis = 120px, то поведение сохраняется. 
Ну и к тому же мне это и нужно -- чтобы вложенные элементы имели высоту 120px по-умолчанию, но могли сжиматься до 40px

Answer (score 0):

Помогли на англоязычном [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size)

В итоге контейнеры не сжимались из-за того, что для них по-умолчанию выставляется `min-width`/`min-height` : `auto`

А выставление конкретного значения вместо `auto` позволяет им начать сжиматься

Ниже обновленный пример с проставленным значением `min-height`

```css
.outer-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 450px;
}

.top-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
  
  background: rgba(200,0,0,.5);
}

.top-container div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 0 1 120px;
  min-height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.bottom-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: none;
  
  background: rgba(0,200,0,.5);
}

.bottom-container div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
   <div class="top-container">
    <div id="first">111</div>
    <div id="second">222</div>
    <div id="third">333</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-container">
    <div id="four">4</div>
    <div id="five">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```